# Saving 1 as number into a ENUM('1','0') field set value as 0

Tags: mysql, enums

Just notice something weird while was saving `1` as integer into a `ENUM('1', '0')`. The value got stored as 0.

```
UPDATE table SET `somefield` = 1 WHERE `id` = 1;

SELECT id, `somefield` WHERE id = 1;

id, somefield
1, 0
```

Is there any way to make it work? I prefer to don't modify DB.

Also, any information about why this happen and the field is not converted would be very appreciated

Comment: `ENUM('1','0')` is a particularly bad idea unless you are trying to win a code obfuscation contest ('0' + 1 = 3, depending on how it's evaluated).  Any value that cleanly casts to and from a string and a number in the dictionary of an `ENUM` is practically *begging* for unexpected behavior.  `TINYINT` is a much more appropriate data type in this case.

Answer (score 2):

When you provide an integer instead of a string for the update value of an enum, it's interpreted as the *index* of the enum values, not the *value*.

Enums, like all of SQL, use 1-based indexing, so for your enum index 1 is `'1'` and index 2 is `'0'`. Anything else is an error.

That means your update statement should result in a `'1'`, not a zero, so either your table is not defined as you say, or your update statement is not as you say.

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78cb7/1) proving this.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET `somefield` = '1' WHERE `id` = 1;
```

The value needs to be specified as a string.